# Building pango-1.32.6 for use in building gtk3 from git

Tags: gnome, compiling

I'm trying to build pango-1.32.6 to use when building gtk+3 from git, but I'm getting the following error:

```
checking for CAIRO... yes
checking which cairo font backends could be used... none
configure: Disabling cairo support
configure: error: *** Could not enable any backends.
*** Must have at least one backend to build Pango.
```

This sounds like an unmet cairo dependency to me. Does anyone know what version it is?

Answer (score 2):

Looking in `configure.ac` around line 356:

```
cairo_required=1.7.6
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(CAIRO, cairo >= $cairo_required, have_cairo=true, AC_MSG_RESULT([no]))
```

So the answer would be 1.7.6!

Edit: This was presumably also the problem [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2013-January/msg00033.html), though probably with a different number, but I didn't have the luxury of being able to downgrade!

Comment: pango-1.36.1 depends cairo-1.12.10

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to downgrade to (or attempt to install) `pango-1.32.5` instead.